# Is there a Hodge structure for smooth proper varieties over $\mathbb{C_p}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, p-adic-hodge-theory

For smooth proper varieties over $\mathbb{Q_p}$, we have several comparison theorems in p-adic Hodge theory, in particular a p-adic Hodge structure.

Now for $\mathbb{C_p}$, is there any such results for smooth proper varieties over $\mathbb{C_p}$?

If the answer is negative, then what is the reason?